# how to detect the roles and features have been modified Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012, powershell-cmdlet

I'm curious that is there any possibility to detect that the roles and features in windows server 2012 have been modified ( for example is that its parameters have been changed/added/removed ) by using powershell or cmdlets?

Comment: Modified from what? Setup? Yesterday? The last time someone installed a feature? If your goal is to ensure the server is in some known good configuration, that's what [DSC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShell/dsc/overview) is intended to solve.

Comment: Yes, you can use `Get-WindowsFeature` to make a baseline and then again when you want to compare. But really DSC is probably the true answer.